# npm install doesn't work in Docker

Tags: docker, npm

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    rubygems build-essential ruby-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm install -gq gulp bower

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD ["gulp", "start:dev"]
```

When I build the image, the npm install command executes with little output and really quickly. I actually build it through docker-compose which does have a volume mounted - and I cannot see the node_modules folder being created on my hose. When I launch a container on this image, I can see there is no node_modules folder. I then execute npm install and things start working - it takes 2-3 minutes to install all the packages and the node_modules folder is indeed created.

What is happening here? What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't npm install work at build time, but then it works at run time?

Comment: You mention a volume, but that isn't shown in any commands or files you included. Please include your docker-compose.yml and output showing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `npm install` should have worked based on your `Dockerfile`. You can see the created files if you run the image without a mounted volume (`DIRNAME`: where your `docker-compose.yml` is located):

`docker run --rm -it DIRNAME_node ls -ahl /usr/src/app`

With `docker build`, all data is stored in the image. So, it's intended that you don't see any files created on your host.

If you mount a volume (generally in Linux, also in a Docker container), it [overlays the directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume). So you can't see the `node_modules` created in the build step.

I suggest you do your tests based on the Docker image itself and don't mount the volume. Then you have an [immutable Docker image](http://sroze.io/2015/12/23/immutable-docker-images/) which is better for deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Also copying up the source and running npm install means that whenever the source code changes, the npm install step cache becomes invalid.

Instead, separate the steps/caches like so;

```
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
```

Comment: don't think is really relevant to the question.. but it is sure a good tip

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I was having the same issue reported in this question and after some research I've found a question with the necessary steps to solve the problem.

In short, the main problem is that during the install wizard I've selected the option "Windows as containers".

**To solve the issue**:

1) **Switch to Linux Containers**: On taskbar, right click on docker icon and click on the option as presented bellow:

[image]

2) Disable "Experimental Features" on Command Line: Open docker/settings and click on Command Line:

[image]

3) Disable Experimental setting on configuration file:: On docker/settings, click on Docker Engine and certify that experimental is set to false:

[image]

The question where I found the solution was related to another problem I was facing when trying to build docker images: [Unspecified error (0x80004005) while running a Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923052/5936119). Both problems were related to the same issue: *when installing docker for the first time I've selected the option "windows as containers"*.
Hope it helps. Cheers