# Unspecified error (0x80004005) while running a Docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

Going thought the onboarding first steps of docker https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding , I run into an issue when running the build command

```
docker build -t <user>/cheers2019 .
```

The error happend at the 6th step, with code error (0x80004005). I am running docker on windows with windows containers.

The full error code:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.31kB
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.11-alpine AS builder
 ---> e116d2efa2ab
Step 2/9 : RUN apk add --no-cache git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 07f79e350f69
Step 3/9 : RUN go get github.com/pdevine/go-asciisprite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cfe4fd4064c3
Step 4/9 : WORKDIR /project
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ba87d64456e
Step 5/9 : COPY cheers.go .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 486d7602dccf
Step 6/9 : RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o cheers cheers.go
 ---> Running in b77dee3bd612
container b77dee3bd612319c299e077116fc68ccf7f166246f85138b0e1cc0e074c8cb2b encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Unspecified error (0x80004005)
[Event Detail: failed to run runc create/exec call for container b77dee3bd612319c299e077116fc68ccf7f166246f85138b0e1cc0e074c8cb2b: exit status 1 Stack Trace:
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*container).startProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:580
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).runCreateCommand
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:471
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc.(*runcRuntime).CreateContainer
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/runtime/runc/runc.go:113
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs.(*gcsCore).ExecProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/core/gcs/gcs.go:351
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:637
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).execProcess-fm
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:253
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.HandlerFunc.ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:72
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Mux).ServeMsg
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:146
github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge.(*Bridge).ListenAndServe.func2.1
        /go/src/github.com/Microsoft/opengcs/service/gcs/bridge/bridge.go:335
runtime.goexit
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandArgs":["/bin/sh","-c","CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags \"-static\"' -o cheers cheers.go"],"WorkingDirectory":"/project","Environment":{"GOLANG_VERSION":"1.11.13","GOPATH":"/go","HOSTNAME":"b77dee3bd612","PATH":"/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0],"OCISpecification":{"ociVersion":"1.0.1-dev","process":{"user":{"uid":0,"gid":0},"args":["/bin/sh","-c","CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags \"-static\"' -o cheers cheers.go"],"env":["PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","HOSTNAME=b77dee3bd612","GOLANG_VERSION=1.11.13","GOPATH=/go"],"cwd":"/project","capabilities":{"bounding":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"effective":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"inheritable":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"],"permitted":["CAP_CHOWN","CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE","CAP_FSETID","CAP_FOWNER","CAP_MKNOD","CAP_NET_RAW","CAP_SETGID","CAP_SETUID","CAP_SETFCAP","CAP_SETPCAP","CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE","CAP_SYS_CHROOT","CAP_KILL","CAP_AUDIT_WRITE"]}},"root":{"path":"rootfs"},"hostname":"b77dee3bd612","mounts":[{"destination":"/proc","type":"proc","source":"proc","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev","type":"tmpfs","source":"tmpfs","options":["nosuid","strictatime","mode=755","size=65536k"]},{"destination":"/dev/pts","type":"devpts","source":"devpts","options":["nosuid","noexec","newinstance","ptmxmode=0666","mode=0620","gid=5"]},{"destination":"/sys","type":"sysfs","source":"sysfs","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","ro"]},{"destination":"/sys/fs/cgroup","type":"cgroup","source":"cgroup","options":["ro","nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/mqueue","type":"mqueue","source":"mqueue","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev"]},{"destination":"/dev/shm","type":"tmpfs","source":"shm","options":["nosuid","noexec","nodev","mode=1777"]}],"linux":{"resources":{},"namespaces":[{"type":"mount"},{"type":"network"},{"type":"uts"},{"type":"pid"},{"type":"ipc"}],"maskedPaths":["/proc/asound","/proc/acpi","/proc/kcore","/proc/keys","/proc/latency_stats","/proc/timer_list","/proc/timer_stats","/proc/sched_debug","/proc/scsi","/sys/firmware"],"readonlyPaths":["/proc/bus","/proc/fs","/proc/irq","/proc/sys","/proc/sysrq-trigger"]},"windows":{"layerFolders":["C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\072ca1f3855a32f3e3b24c2fe4ca8dea9853d4fb64207407094332a2d6541458","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\c45071b2eff55610a9d9b3f430b8e5fa3ff65465e59b8d5a63a61e744ca94c48","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\6890c90396b8fcd14669837530eef071ec5e3f10dda6724478c7ab1b58752307","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\a1998eef0068aac5fb61f53e87ce8d6d46eaf5c83f7eab36cb745fb57ad72e8a","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\f311f4698a5c1eb5e8800ef04c6066177112d76afc18d089fcf2cd5642712a01","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\5e7e640cace36a63707967e7109604dacc800b8163eb04a4be7f346ff38ba867","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\a2a8b17328e92e236a3d30841abed7b815188a3d63e2432272f772acda4ec75d","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\d774068efa88052dab131c32c40832302f547dd4737738ca19873e0c3bed0074","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\b433fd6793fe572e509619d719280574a3b1860dbcc647ec6629695666227ca5","C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\lcow\\b77dee3bd612319c299e077116fc68ccf7f166246f85138b0e1cc0e074c8cb2b"],"hyperv":{},"network":{"endpointList":["0FFBAC8D-5E31-4C4F-A753-85C5148C437D"],"allowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}}}}
```

Any idea of how I should run my builds in docker ?

Comment: I had to use "winpty docker run -it --rm user/cheers2019" to run it but the build passes for me. 

I'm using "Git for windows" aka MINGW64 as command shell, maybe try with a different shell.

Are you using a compatible version of Windows anyways ? Familly isn't supported.

Comment: @job3dot5 I am on Windows 10 Professional. I tried the command in cygwin with winpty but I ran into the same error. Most of the time I use either the regular windows cmd or powershell. Although I can run the prebuilds I dowload, but not being able to make them myself is a huge inconvenient.

Comment: What is your "Docker for Desktop" version ? I lately tried the latest but I had issues, now I'm back to version 2.0.0.3  Maybe try that.

Comment: @job3dot5 I am using the last version in date (2.1.0.2), but as you pointed out going for an older one might solve my problem. I will come back if I encounter more issues. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same error. I don' know if it comes from the fact that during installation I checked "only Windows containers", but it switched to Windows containers in Docker For Windows.

[image: Click in Docker icon in right corner]

So the solution is to click **switch to Linux container**, then I clean all :

```
docker system prune
```

Then I run again:

```
docker build -t <user>/cheers2019 .
```

Now it works for me.
Here is my Docker version :

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:37 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:29:19 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 2):

I have Trying to change the experimental.

Check : `Docker version` in Console if experimental is false in both Client and Server.

Then you can change in C:\Users\.docker
in `config.json` you change **experimental":"enabled"**
then in `daemon.json` you change **"experimental": true**
then after save I run again.
`docker build -t <user>/cheers2019 .`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I was having the same problem reported in the current question and the following issue as well: [NPM Install doesn't work in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287999/npm-install-doesnt-work-in-docker).

To solve the issue I've combined both solutions:

1. @JPBlanc  (**Switch to Linux Containers**)
2. @Muhammad (**disable experimental on command line & configuration file**)

How I did it:

1) **Switch to Linux Containers**: On taskbar, right click on docker icon and click on the option as presented bellow:

[image]

2) **Disable "Experimental Features" on Command Line**: Open docker/settings and click on *Command Line*:

[image]

3) **Disable Experimental setting on configuration file:**: On docker/settings, click on *Docker Engine* and certify that *experimental* is set to false:

[image]

Hope it helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

replace CRLF characters with LF for Windows in a tool like Notepad++ and rerun.